# In Android how to get the list of files in sys folder

Tags: android, file

I want to get the list of files which are present in the /sys/ folder of the android Os .Can any one help me out to get the result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Think that your phone must have the root access to that.

Comment: Phone must be rooted to access that folder

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new File("/sys/").listFiles()`, but this system folder might be protected by the system